# Python Regular Expression Why Quantifier (+) is not greedy

Tags: python, regex

Input: `asjkd http://www.as.com/as/g/ff askl`

Expected output: `http://www.as.com/as/g/ff`

When I try below I am getting expected output

```
pattern=re.compile(r'http[\w./:]+')
print(pattern.search("asjkd http://www.as.com/as/g/ff askl"))
```

Why isn't the `+` quantifier greedy here? I was expecting it to be greedy. Here actually not being greedy is helping to find the right answer.

Comment: The space is not matched by your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* greedy. It stops matching when it hits the space because `[\w./:]` doesn't match a space. A space isn't a [word character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-32) (alphanumeric or underscore), dot, slash, or colon.

Change `+` to `+?` and you can see what happens when it's non-greedy.

**Greedy**

```
>>> pattern=re.compile(r'http[\w./:]+')
>>> print(pattern.search("asjkd http://www.as.com/as/g/ff askl"))
<re.Match object; span=(6, 31), match='http://www.as.com/as/g/ff'>
```

**Non-greedy**

```
>>> pattern=re.compile(r'http[\w./:]+?')
>>> print(pattern.search("asjkd http://www.as.com/as/g/ff askl"))
<re.Match object; span=(6, 11), match='http:'>
```

It matches a single character `:`!